# mongoose put does not check for required field

Tags: node.js, api, express, mongoose, put

I am making nodejs API and I have a user model. Some fields are required. When trigger post it will tell me that some fields required so no save will be done, but when I do it with put it will replace it even if validation is wrong, or even if there is a required field and is missing, but duplicates run good.

this is the model of user

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

        firstName: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, 'the firstName is missing'],
                validate: [(val) => validator.isAlpha(val, ['fr-FR']), 'not valid first name'],
        },
        lastName: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, 'the lastName is missing'],
                validate: [(val) => validator.isAlpha(val, ['fr-FR']), 'not valid last name'],
        },
        phoneNumber: {
                type: String,
                required: [true, 'the phoneNumber is missing'],
                unique: [true, 'phoneNumber already in use'],
                validate: [(val) => validator.isMobilePhone(val,['ar-DZ']), 'not valid phone number'],
        },
        email : {
                type: String,
                required: [true, 'the email is missing'],
                unique: [true, 'email already in use'],
                validate: [validator.isEmail, 'not valid email'],
        },
        role: {
                type : String,
                "enum" : ['teacher', 'student'],
                required : [true, 'the user `s role is missing'],
        }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

this is where I handle put

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('../../../../models/user');

router.put('/', (req, res) => {

        //get the new user object
        const userId = req.body.userId;
        User.replaceOne({
                _id: userId
        },
                {
                        _id: userId,
                        firstName: req.body.firstName,
                        lastName: req.body.lastName,
                        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        role: req.body.role
                })
        .exec()
        .then(response => {
                res.status(200).json(response);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

so I tried to test those, by postman, I wanted from mongoose to do that automatically, I thought about splitting it and redirect it to delete then post, but i will need to do the checking first, or just do the checking manually, and because am using `api`, I don't want to use the patch method so I don't track the user for what changes he did in the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You can, instead of `replaceOne()` use `updateOne()` or `findOneAndUpdate()` with turned on validators (as they are of by default), like so:

```
User.updateOne({_id: userId},
               {
                   _id: userId,
                   firstName: req.body.firstName,
                   lastName: req.body.lastName,
                   phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                   email: req.body.email,
                   role: req.body.role
               },
               {runValidators: true})
.then(response => {
    res.status(200).json(response);
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Or you can call the `validate()` on the new instance of the model and if it is valid continue with update logic, e.g.

```
let user = new User({_id: userId,
                   firstName: req.body.firstName,
                   lastName: req.body.lastName,
                   phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                   email: req.body.email,
                   role: req.body.role});
user.validate()
.then(() => {
    // update logic
})
.catch((err) => {
    // handle error
})
```

Look for more information on [Mongoose validation with update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators).

Comment: thank you , i needed the replaceone() so i dont truck the changes in the front-end, but i didnt know about the argument to turn on validator, so am using it with replaceone()